# #HTML Input and output variables(IXL Bot)

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I'm trying to make a bot that does equations that a standard calculator can't. I'm okay with using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I want it to do this: If I put a specific question in the textbox, like "Is 48 a composite or prime number?" it sends an alert and in the alert, it says "Composite" but I want it so I can put in multiple questions in the textbox, for now, I can only have one question or it crashes. Here is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="text here"></input>
    <button type="button" id="u" onclick="run()">submit</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var a = 1;
        function run() {
            if (document.getElementById("text").value.includes("Is 48 a prime number or a composite number?")) {
                alert("Composite");
                document.body.innerHTML += "<li>attempt #" + a + ": correct";
                a++
            } else {
                alert("try again!")
                document.body.innerHTML += "<li>attempt #" + a + ": try again";
                a++
            }


        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I need help with this part. I need so multiple questions can be put in the textbox and a different output comes out every time.

```
var a = 1;
function run() {
    if (document.getElementById("text").value.includes("Is 48 a prime number or a composite number?")) {
        alert("Composite");
    }
}
```

I tried to copy and paste the code a few times it didn't work. I tried to change the variable name the thing crashed.

Thank you to anyone who helps.

I'm expecting a textbox where if you put in a question it answers but it is a word problem so a normal calculator won't always work.

Comment: This is a broad area you are talking about. In general these kind of requirements can be address with NLP which is Natural Language Processing which includes AI and some advance programing skills. refer https://www.techtarget.com/searchenterpriseai/definition/natural-language-processing-NLP

Comment: Simply if you going to address this with if else statements you will end up with thousands of if else conditions for each text input. I am happy  your passionate in programming and you are trying to solve this particular problem within your knowledge level. It is a progressive attitude and keep learning

Comment: Yes, but could you tell me how to do it

Comment: Lizzard Dev what do you want? Like a quiz with questions and answers? An 'deep' quiz , with no answers programmatically , envolves , deep programming . If you want a quiz with predefined questions and answers I can help

Comment: Kind of. I want a textbox in which you can put in questions, and answers come out. I'd like to use HTML, CSS, JAVA, Javascript, or PHP. I will accept any other language but 
 I need to test if it works in the web hosting program I use. The thing is that I want to build up on this and my final result will be that it will be like an FAQ but if you put in specific questions it outputs specific answers. But to make it less complicated I just want to start it out with just if you put a specific question into the textbox it gives you an answer like a math problem.

Comment: And also that there can be hundreds of questions.